# reading in shapefiles and turning them into dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shapefile

I have a script that does some calculations on shapefiles that I would like to automate and have the values transferred into a new table.
I can read in the list of shapefiles, but I need to convert them all to dataframes before I can do calculations, not sure how to continue to automate this process.

I select the folder where I have the shapefiles loaded in

```
Directory<-"E:/Outputs/BAU-CCSM4/Run0"
```

I create a list of the shapefiles

```
filename <- list.files(Directory, pattern="*.shp", full.names=FALSE)
```

I parse out the .shp with just basename in order for the readOGR to work

```
filenames<- basename(file_path_sans_ext(filename))
```

I create a loop that reads in all the files and assigns their names

```
for (i in 1:length(filename)) assign(paste(filename[i]), readOGR(Directory, filenames[i]))
```

I want to covert all the files that I read, into data.frames, and then loop through my calculation to be performed on each dataframe and then have the final values be outputed into a new table. But I am unsure how to create a new loop to create that as trying to call the files I get an error because the data.frame function needs it to be formatted into data.frame(shapefilename) with the character -------> ` around shapefilename.

Is there another way to format by variable with the character ` for the data.frame function or another way to loop my shapefiles to be read in as a dataframe.

...

for the script part it would be something along the lines of

```
filenames[i]$TotalArea <-c ((filenames[i]$Area) - ((filenames[i]$Area)* (filenames[i]$YieldRed)))
write.csv(filenames[i], file="Newtable")
```

Not sure if this will work but got to get the first part working before I am here.

Comment: Use the library rgdal, its a really strong spatial data system. Then you can simply use `as.data.frame( readOGR() )`. Further you can use `gsub()` on your `list.files()` to get rid of the .shp characters instead of `basename()`

Comment: if all you want is the `data.frame`, just use `read.dbf` (`foreign` package)

Comment: Thank you Badger, the as.data.frame() was what I was missing :)

Comment: For `sp` shapefiles with integrated data.frames (Spatial*DataFrame), you can access the data.frame with `shapefile@data`, which should return the same thing as `sp::as.data.frame.Spatial*DataFrame`.